# Looping through a txt file

Tags: python, file, txt

I have a txt file with a list of artists, songs, and genres in the following format:

```
song 1
genre 1 
artist 1

song 2
genre 2
artist 2

etc.
```

I'm given an artists name and if the artist is in the file I have to return the name of their song. The code I've managed to write is:

```
afile = open('music.txt')
header = afile.readline()
artists = afile.readlines()
afile.close()

for art in artists:
    if art == artist:
```

How could I get the name of the song that is two lines above the artists name? It's also possible that an artists appears several times with different songs.

Comment: What if an artist has multiple songs?

Comment: why do you need `header`? You don't have any header in your example file

Answer (score 1):

First, read your file into a list. I'm assuming the format of your file is fixed: it contains

- A line specifying song name
- A line specifying genre
- A line specifying artist
- A blank line
- Repeat

Note that since there doesn't seem to be a header, you don't need the initial `header = afile.readline()`

Let's say you read all the lines of your file into a list called `lines`

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in afile] 
# You could also do 
# lines = afile.readlines()
# but that would leave behind trailing line breaks at the end of each line
```

Now, you know that

- Starting at the first line, every fourth line is the song name. So slice the `lines` list to take every fourth line, starting at the first line and save it as a list called `songs`

```
songs = lines[0::4]
```

- Do the same thing for the other information:

```
genres = lines[1::4]
artists = lines[2::4]
```

Now, we can `zip()` these lists to iterate over them simultaneously, and print the songs for the artists that match the one we're looking for:

```
look_for_artist = "artist 2"

print(f"Songs by {look_for_artist}:")
for artist, genre, song in zip(artists, genres, songs):
    if artist == look_for_artist:
        print(song, genre)
        # if you know that every artist has only one song, you can break the loop here since you found it already
        # break
```

If you were doing this for a bunch of artists, I'd recommend you read the data into a dictionary [(or a `collections.defaultdict`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) first. Then, you can look up the value of the dictionary for the given artist and this will be much faster than looping over the lists.

To account for the case when a single artist can have multiple songs, we're going to use a dictionary where the keys are the artist's name, and values are a list containing all the songs by them.

```
import collections
lookup_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for artist, genre, song in zip(artists, genres, songs):
    lookup_dict[artist].append((genre, song))
```

Then, all you need to do is:

```
for genre, song in lookup_dict[look_for_artist]:
   print(song, genre)
```

You can remove the need to read the entire file into a list and then process it into a dictionary by reading the file line-by-line in groups of four lines, but I will leave that as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

Start at the second element (as that is where the first artist is) and scan every 4th element for the artist. If the `i-th` element of `linelist` matches `artist`, print the song (which is at `i-2`).

```
for i in range(2, 100, 4):
    if linelist[i] == artist:
        print(linelist[i-2])
```

Comment: `afile.readlines()` already gives you a list

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Good point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each artist has only one song (or you are searching for the first match) you could solve it like this:

```py
def check_artist(chosen_artist):
    afile = open('music.txt')
    while afile:
        song = afile.readline()
        afile.readline() # Ignore the second line
        artist = afile.readline()
        if atrist == chosen_artist:
            return song.split("\n")
        afile.readline() # Ignore the empty line
    afile.close()
    return "The artists do not have a song"
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers until now are valid, but they do rely on the fact that the format is always 4 lines. Here is code that also does work if there is missing data or there is more data:

```
music = []
with open("music.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        
        # continue if line is empty
        if not line:
            continue
        key = line.pop(0)
        value = ' '.join(line)
        
        # check for keys
        if key=='song':
            music.append({key: value})
        if key=='genre':
            music[-1].update({key: value})
        if key=='artist':
            music[-1].update({key: value})
```

This is also extendable if your format later includes another key like **'album'**.

If you're using python3.10 you could look into pattern matching to further simplify the code.